# Zero-free region of $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am new to the Riemann zeta function.

In the beginning of section 2 of [Bruce c. Berndt, the number of zeros for $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/2.Part_4.577), J. London Math. Soc. (2), Vol 2, 1970, p. 577-580, the author made the following claim:

> From the general theory of Dirichlet series, $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$ has a right half-plane free of zeros.

Could someone kindly elaborate on the above claim and point out which result from the "general theory of Dirichlet series" that the author was using please?

Comment: If $f(s)=a_k/k^s+ \sum_{n\ge k+1}a_n/n^s$ where $k$ is the first index for which $a_k \ne 0$ then there is some real $c_0$ for which $|a_k|/k^c>   \sum_{n \ge k+1}|a_n|/n^c$ for all $c\ge c_0$ so $f(s) \ne 0$ when $\Re s > c_0$

Comment: Thanks for your generous help once again! @Conrad